# Doubt regarding a statement in Qm

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have read in a text that if potential is nowhere infinite and $\psi$ and $\psi '$ is $0$ at given point then $\psi$ will be zero everywhere. How do we prove the statement?

Comment: Where did you read this ?  Give a title, author and ideally a link if possible to an abstract if it's a paper.

Comment: I read it from mitocw quantum mechanics lecture notes  last line of page no 6 of PDF whoose link is

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just mathematics, not quantum theory.

If you you evaluate the differential equation at some point $x_0$ where $\psi(x_0)=0$ and $\psi'(x_0)=0$ you get $\psi''(x_0)=0$.

If $V(x)\to\infty$ anywhere it means we end up multiplying zero by infinity which is not not mathematically sensible, so that case is excluded.  If we have $V(x)$ finite everywhere that problem does not happen.

Now let's try and evaluate $\psi'''(x_0)$.  We differentiate the differential equation.  You'll see if you do that that $\psi'''(x_0)=0$ is also required.

We can keep doing this to find the values of higher order derivatives of $\psi(x)$ at $x_0$ and they will all be zero because the lower order derivatives are zero and we're always multiply something finite by zero.

So we can now construct the expression for the Taylor expansion of $\psi(x)$ around the point $x_0$.  We get this :

$$\psi(x_0+x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x-x_0)^k}{k!}\psi^{(k)}(x_0)$$

But we've just shown that all the $\psi^{(k)}(x_0)=0$ and so $\psi(x)$ is zero everywhere.

Comment: Ok Thanks my doubt is clear now.

Comment: @sachinrawat in that case, please mark this question as answered! :)

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not sure about the specificities of the problem as the statement is vague. I'll try to address this for a one-dimensional case.*

We have the TISE
$$\hat{\mathcal{H}}\left|\psi\right> = E\left|\psi\right>,$$
$$\left(\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V(\hat{x})\right)\left|\psi\right> = E\left|\psi\right>.$$
For the one-dimensional problem, position representation of the TISE gives,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x) = \left(E-V(x)\right)\psi(x).$$
Now if the potential is infinite in some region, then $\psi(x)$ becomes zero in that region and we have to solve for the rest of the region with appropriate boundary conditions. (*Ref. One-Dimensional infinite potential well problem for motivation*).

Assuming the potential is nowhere infinite, we can rewrite the above equation as,
$$\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2} = -k^2\psi(x),$$
where $k=-\frac{2m\left(E-V(x)\right)}{\hbar^2}$.

If $k^2>0$, solving for $\psi(x)$ we get,
$$\psi(x) = Acos(kx)+Bsin(kx).$$
Now we know that the wavefunction and it's derivative are zero at some point, say at $x=a$. We have to find $\psi(x)$ such that $\psi(a)$ and $\psi'(a)$ are both zero. Imposing these conditions give either $B=0$ or $A=0$. If $B=0$, then if we try to find a non trivial solution, we get $sin(ka)=0$ and $cos(ka)=0$, both of which cannot be satisfied simultaneously. Hence $A=0$ and we end up with the trivial solution. Similar argument holds for the case when $A=0$.

If $k^2<0$, solving for $\psi(x)$ we get,
$$\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}.$$

Again if we say at $x=a$ the wavefunction and it's derivate are zero, and if we impose these conditions we get $A=0$ and $B=0$ and hence the trivial solution.

If $k^2=0$, we naturally get the trivial solution $\psi(x)=0$ everywhere.

Comment: But V is not constant how can you write psi as linear combination of sine and cosine

Comment: V(x) need not be constant for this to work. You just have to split the entire space into regions where $k^2>0$ and $k^2<0$. If $x=a$ lies in any one of these regions, wavefunction becomes zero everywhere in that region. Once it is zero everywhere in that region, you can show that it is zero everywhere else by imposing suitable boundary conditions. Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

One should invoke continuity and differentiability of the wave function which is assumed in QM. So the first line where it is said that the potential cannot be Infinity, translates to wave function's property in the fact that,
The wave function then can't have non continuity and non differentiability in its representation over space. i.e. the wave function can't have sudden jumps and has to be smooth everywhere.

Now for the second part where it is written that ψ and its first derivative is zero at some point, use the first fact that ψ has to be continuous and differentiable, but since its value is zero, and it first derivative is also zero. that means in the neighbourhood of that point there is no chance that the value of function be greater than zero (as the rate of change is zero for that neighbourhood), and so on and on to the next nearest neighbourhood of points, which ultimately means ψ equal to zero everywhere. Try to think of it in terms of mathematical functions, if possible.

Comment: There is a subtle assumption involved when you say that the wavefunction is zero everywhere in the neighbourhood of the point where the wavefunction and its first derivative are zero. This is true only when all the higher derivatives are also zero. This in fact works for this problem as shown by @StephenG in his answer.
As a counter example, consider the function $f(x) = x^2$. The function and its derivative are zero at $x=0$, but the function is not $0$ everywhere. This is because  the function has a non vanishing second derivative.

Comment: I've deleted a number of inappropriate comments and/or responses to them.

Comment: @AjayShanmugaSakthivasan Thanks for pointing it out. I assumed that the my comment was talking about the schrodinger equation. Neverthless I should have mentioned this in my comment, sincere thanks.